# Adjust width of text field in contact form 7

Tags: html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am new to WordPress . I used a plugin contact form 7, And I need to adjust its width of fields. for now it is 100 % width.

By doing some google I came to know that I need to edit custom CSS for this and I added these lines but still nothing

```
input[type="text"]
{
background-color: #fff;
color: #000;
width: 50%;
}
```

And i am using avada theme

Comment: try this:  .wpcf7-form input[type="text"]

Comment: documentation: http://contactform7.com/styling-contact-form/

Answer (score 3):

I have solved the problem using this:

```
.wpcf7-form.init label{width:100%; max-width:inherit;}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wanna adjust all your fields to be 100 % width, you can simply use this css:

```
input {
 width: 100%;
}
```

If you need to specify certain fields:

```
input[type="text"] {
 width: 100%;
}
```

As [mentioned](/questions/38051052/adjust-width-of-text-field-in-contact-form-7#comment63545085_38051052), there's a [styling guide](https://contactform7.com/styling-contact-form/).

Answer (score 1):

```
input[type=text], #respond textarea, .post-password-form input[type=password], .wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-date, .wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-number, .wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-quiz, .wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-select, .wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-text, .wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-textarea {
    width: 59%;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    padding: 17px 30px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #797979;
    font-family: "Crimson Text",serif;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

You have to change the "width" element, in percentage.

Answer (score 1):

It might not work because the plugin `css` styles are overridden by other styles. You might need to either add `!important` to your property as shown below.

```html
input[type="text"] {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  width: 50% !important;
}
```

This is usually not recommended see this article https://uxengineer.com/css-specificity-avoid-important-css/.

The best approach is to add a class or id before the css style to apply the styling only to that element. See the full code below:

```html
#form_container_with_contact_form input[type="text"] {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the text field on browser and apply the same style to the class assigned to the input as per scope. I think the contact form input usually has a class name "input". Something like this might help

```
.et_pb_contact p input
{
background-color: #fff;
color: #000;
width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The example bellow is for **Contact form 7 Wordpress** - Inside form edit section - Use **"80/"** or **"40/"** depends the size you want
Or **80x10** **for textarea**

```
<label> name
    [text* your-name autocomplete:name **80/**] </label>

<label> email
    [email* your-email autocomplete:email **80/**] </label>

<label> subject
    [text* your-subject **80/**] </label>
```

or

```
<label> name
    [text* your-name autocomplete:name **80/**] </label>

<label> email
    [email* your-email autocomplete:email **80/**] </label>

<label> subject
    [text* your-subject **80x10**] </label>
```